# Java Recursive File Copy optimization

Tags: java, file, pdf, optimization, copy

I have a little application which copy PDF files (subfolders) to a destination folder. But it works very slow, I would like to optimize it. Can you help me?

The code:

```
    public void pdfFolderCopy(File src, File dest)
            throws IOException {
        if (src.isDirectory()) {
            if (!dest.exists()) {
                dest.mkdir();
            }
            String files[] = src.list();
            for (String file : files) {
                File srcFile = new File(src, file);
                File destFile = new File(dest, file);
                pdfFolderCopy(srcFile, destFile);
            }
        } else {
            if (!dest.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Copying: " + src);
                //Use the Apache IO copyFile method:
                FileUtils.copyFile(src, dest);
            }
        }
    }
```

It is runs about one and a half minutes if every files are already exist. And about 5 minutes, if we need to copy about 500 files.

Comment: Can not see why this should be so slow.  Try logging some times

Comment: I think it depends on the size of the files as well.How big are they??

Comment: There are about 15.000 files with avarage 100K fileszie.

Comment: Maybe multithreaded copy can work faster. For example, first four root folders can be handled by four threads. I dont know if File objects can be reused for different files but it could be faster without re-creating for every file. Check the biggest file, create one object for that, re-use it for all (Im not sure if this deletes all stuff in your HDD so you should be cautious)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: Multithreading may be a good idea, but reusing of `File` is nonsense. `File` is a cheap object, sort of wrapped `String` and it's immutable. Creating a few thousands of them may take some milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to simply invoke a process doing

```
/bin/cp -R -n src dest
```

where `-R` means recursive and `-n` means don't overwrite. There's a good chance that the OS can do this faster then you. No idea what's the corresponding command for Windows or other OS.

For this you need just

```
new ProcessBuilder()
.command("/bin/cp", "-R", "-n", src.toString(), dest.toString())
.start();
```

In case you want to do it in Java, I'd try some minor changes:

- `dest.mkdir()` without any check works and might be a bit faster
- `listFiles` might be faster than composing them manually (probably irrelevant)
- once you've created a `dest` folder yourself, you don't need to check if there are any pre-existing files there

I guess, multithreading may lead to a nice speedup: Let the main thread create copying jobs and submit them to some executor (with some 4-8 threads).

Note that such multithreaded writes may lead to higher disk fragmentation, but I wouldn't care. If I had to, then I'd create file reding jobs instead, let them return the file content (n * 100 KB is nothing), and use a single writer thread.

Answer (score 2):

The only real time consuming task in your code is `FileUtils.copyFile()`. The necessary time will growing according to the number of files to copy and their size.

Regarding your code I would suggest to extract the check for `dest` directory since it shouldn't change during the copy process. Check and create the `dest` directory before you start `pdfFolderCopy`.

Comment: Your last paragraph makes no sense to me. The test `dest.exists()` will test the existence of the directory and nothing gets copied.